# Get old settinmgs from VS-2010 into VS-2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I start VS-2013 for the first time and an older Version of VS is installed I get the question if I want to take over old settings.

Now I have a machine were I installed VS-2013 and I pressed no on the question if old Settings should be imported. This was a mistake. What ss the way to force VS-2013 to requery me for the older Settings of the installed VS-2010?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio has an Import/Export settings option on the Tools menu.  Try exporting settings from 2010.  Then, import into 2013.

Comment: This works partially, but the important Settings (Keyboard) are transfered.